# Hanging TO or FROM or ON in this situation

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-construction

I have seen the sentence in a grammar book:

**"There are hanging some ripe mangoes TO the twig of the tree."**

But earlier I always used ON and FROM in this situation.

Explain (hanging) on, from and to.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I phrase your sentence:

There are some ripe mangoes hanging from the twig of the tree.

When using 'is' you refer to one noun.  When using 'are' you refer to two nouns or a plural noun.

For use of "on" "to" or "from" with the continuous verb "hanging":
hanging on to (*on to* also *onto* prepositional use indicating position or direction. 
hanging from (*from* indicates the origin)

Lastly, it is more common to place the subject *some ripe mangos* before the verb.